# XML DTD with an entity that accepts XHTML P entry

Tags: xml, xhtml, dtd

How to declare an XML DTD extending XHTML DTD? That is, I want to say that an element should accept anything that the P tag of XHTML accepts.

See my current XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE question SYSTEM "question.dtd">

<question id="1" level="0" subject="graphs">
  <text>o texto da questão.</text>
  <explanation>a explicação.</explanation>
  <choice type="correct">
    <text>primeira possivel resposta</text>
    <explanation>explicacao da resposta</explanation>
  </choice>
  <choice type="incorrect">
    <text>segunda possivel resposta</text>
    <explanation>segunda explicacao da resposta</explanation>
  </choice>
</question>
```

and my DTD

```
<!ELEMENT question (text,explanation,choice+) >
<!ATTLIST question
      level   CDATA #REQUIRED
      subject CDATA #REQUIRED
      id      CDATA #REQUIRED >

<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT explanation (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT choice (text,explanation) >
<!ATTLIST choice
      type (correct|incorrect) "correct" >
```

But the dtd above does not validate the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE question SYSTEM "question.dtd">

<question id="1" level="0" subject="graphs">

  <text>o texto da questão. Veja a figura <img
  src="teste.png"/> para maiores detalhes.</text>

  <explanation>a explicação.</explanation>
  <choice type="correct">
    <text>primeira possivel resposta</text>
    <explanation>explicacao da resposta</explanation>
  </choice>
  <choice type="incorrect">
    <text>segunda possivel resposta</text>
    <explanation>segunda explicacao da resposta</explanation>
  </choice>
</question>
```

Comment: What about the reference source for XHTML DTDs :https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html

Comment: Or http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/extend-an-existing-dtd.165168/

Comment: Imagine that I want to declare a type of document as a collection of paragraphs, and each paragraph being the XHTML paragraph element.

Comment: @MrLister in your example, I am assuming that  `%p`  is not enough, I would still need to say that this `p` is the XHTML tag `p`, right?

Comment: @MrLister you are right, I should not have said 'extending'. I updated the question with examples. I would like to reuse the p tag from XHTML. I am doing a DTD from scratch. The second link from jim-garrison above kind of provide the answer, I have only to figure out the correct way to mention the XHTML DTD.